# Response getting as HeaderTransfer-Encoding: chunked using Httpclient in Java

Tags: java, soap

Im using Httpclient to call a web service in Java. The request I've copied from SOAP UI and pasted as request XML. In SOAP UI, I'm able to get response, but in my code level, it doesnt. It throws

```
Reponse HeaderTransfer-Encoding: chunked
Reponse HeaderDate: Mon, 25 Sep 2017 11:54:06 GMT
Reponse Header END...
Negative array size
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my code

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                        int timeoutConnection = 15000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                        int timeoutSocket = 35000;
                        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

                        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("<SOAP End point>");
                        httppost.setHeader("soapaction", "<Action>");
                        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

                        final StringBuffer soap = new StringBuffer();
                        soap.append("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:web=\"http://webservices.bankfusion.trapedza.com\" xmlns:att=\"http://www.misys.com/bankfusion/attributes\" xmlns:head=\"http://www.misys.com/eqf/types/header\">");
// and so on for soap appending

                        System.out.println(soap);

                        try {
                            HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(soap.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);
                            httppost.setEntity(entity); 
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);// calling server\
                            System.out.println("Response:"+response);
                            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();  //get response
                            System.out.println("Reponse Header Begin...");          // response headers
                            System.out.println("StatusLine:"+response.getStatusLine());
                            Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
                            for(Header h:headers){
                                System.out.println("Reponse Header"+h.getName() + ": " + h.getValue());
                            }
                            System.out.println("Reponse Header END...");
                            if (r_entity != null) {       
                                if((int) r_entity.getContentLength() > 0) {
                                    result = new byte[(int) r_entity.getContentLength()];  
                                    if (r_entity.isStreaming()) {
                                        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(
                                                r_entity.getContent());
                                        is.readFully(result);
                                    }   
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Negative array size");
                                }

                            }
                        } catch (Exception E) {
                            System.out.println("Exception While Connecting");
                            E.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

What could be the issue here? How can I solve it

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated